# JSON as tree in Jersey

Tags: json, jersey

I'm not really a big fan of maintaining a number of POJOs for an API that I'm working on. I'm thinking that (in some cases at least), it would be preferable to consume incoming JSON data as a tree of sorts.

Something like this, maybe: data.getArray('people').getIndex(0).getLong('personId');

Answer (score 0):

You can use the low-level JSON support provided by jettison - see http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e1132